# How is CORP different from CORS?

Tags: cors, cross-origin-resource-policy

I am not a security specialist and have difficulty figuring out the difference between [Cross-Origin Resource Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)) and CORS. I see that both rely on a header sent by the server, and trusts the browser to not allow server content to be delivered to the requester in the browser should the server say so. Where did I understand it wrongly?

Comment: I agree the difference between CORP and CORS isn’t well described anywhere — not even at MDN. But do note that the MDN article at least says this: _“The policy is only effective for no-cors requests, which are issued by default for CORS-safelisted methods/headers.”_ That’s a key point: what that’s saying is, **CORP only affects cross-origin requests that can already be made without requiring CORS to relax the same-origin policy** — that is, requests which are already allowed by the same-origin policy, such as cross-origin requests for images, CSS stylesheets, and for JavaScript scripts.

Comment: This question is anyway probably better suited to https://security.stackexchange.com — and at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/262409/86150 actually already has an answer. To quote that:  _“CORP is basically the opposite of CORS. CORP is a way of tightening the same-origin policy… it could in some cases protect a site's users from attacks that compromise the browser security model (as Spectre did/does) by not processing the response even in situations where same-origin policy would allow it (such as scripts or images).”_

Answer (score 1):

When a website requests resources from a different origin, it is considered a **cross-origin request**. Browsers implement a **same-origin policy** to restrict such requests. The same-origin policy allows a website to access data from another page only if both pages have the same origin.
We can alter this behavior through the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

However, the same-origin policy **does not** prevent the browser from embedding resources from other origins. For example, it can display images using the `<img>` tag, or play media using `<video>` even if those resources come from other origins. We can disallow other origins from embedding our resources by configuring the Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy (CORP).